# What he does vs What does he do?

Tags: word-choice, questions, do-support

What's the difference between them? and when do we 
use "What he does" and "What does he do"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What he does**
>
> **What  does he  do?**

What  he  does  is  an  incomplete  sentence. It  can not  stand on  its  own. It  may  be  part  a  sentence  or  a  part of  an  indirect  question.

For example, you  may  ask someone *what does  he  do*?

The  expected answer may be:  He  is  a  teacher.

If  you  want  to be  polite , you may  ask  an  Indirect  question  such  as:

> **Do  you  know  what  he  does?**

The  expected  answer  might  be:

**Yes.  I  know  what  he  does. He  is  a  teacher**

Structure:

Direct  question:

What+ helping  ver b+ subject+ do( main verb)

Here  helping verb   follows  the  wh-word.

The second  part  of  a  complex  sentence  or  an Indirect  question  is   **what  he  does**

The  structure  is:

What + subject+ main verb( does)

However, sometimes  What  he  does? may  be  question  with  a  rising  tone  in  speech  or  a  question  mark  in the  end in writing?

What  he  does?

Here  is  two  links  which  help  us  to  know  the  differences.

https://www.espressoenglish.net/direct-and-indirect-questions-in-english/

https://englishwithkim.com/rising-intonation-questions/

Answer (score 0):

What is mostly used for two things:

1.

**asking for information** specifying something.

*"what is your name?"*

asking for repetition of something not heard or confirmation of something not 
understood.

*"what? I can't hear you"*

2.

**the thing that** / things that (used in specifying something).

*"what we need is a commitment"*

(referring to the whole of an amount) whatever.

*"I want to do what I can to make a difference"*

Comment: This does not answer the question.